# PostgreSQL user password change from MD5 to scram-sha-265

Tags: postgresql, authentication, password-hash

I was looking at this [Change PostgreSQL password encryption from MD5 to SHA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333053/change-postgresql-password-encryption-from-md5-to-sha) question to figure out how to change the hashing of user passwords in Postgres to something other than MD5 since from what I understand it's basically obsolete now.

But I'm curious if a change is going to be required in the `pg_hpa.conf` file for the server, as according to this tutorial https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/23/configure-postgresql-to-allow-remote-connection.html you need to add the following to it:

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
```

Will the "md5" need to be changed? Or is it purely there to specify a password is required, and won't be affected when changing hashing function to scram-sha-256?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retain `md5` as an authentication method in `pg_hba.conf` even if you change `password_encryption` to `scram-sha-256`. It is just unusual to do so.

The main reason it is unusual is that with `password_encryption = scram-sha-256`, the client must understand the new hashing method anyway to be able to calculate the hashed password from the password entered by the user. Then why not use it for a more secure authentication as well?

To avoid confusion, I'd like to add that there are two different password hashing operations going on in PostgreSQL:

1. The password the user enters is hashed (together with the user name) to produce the actual PostgreSQL password, as stored in `pg_authid`. This is to avoid the problem that someone steals the password and reuses it on other systems.
2. During authentication, the server challenges the client to produce a hash of the password (which is already hashed from the previous step) with a certain salt. This “doubly hashed” password is then sent over the line.

Your question, in other words, was: Can we use `scram-sha-256` for the first point and `md5` for the second?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially my question. I was unsure if password_encryption had any affect on the authentication method, and what the best practice would be. To verify, it would make sense to change the second to match the first?

Comment: Absolutely. You'd get better security for free.